# How a user can pick up several records in a table

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

I apologize for probably silly question, but I've already dont know which words to use for searching what i need. I have the good programming experience but am pretty new to Access.

I have a form with the controls, also it has a subform with read-only list of people contacts. This list is populated by a dynamic query from multiple tables, so i don't know in design-time the count and names of all fields. The user wants to be able to manually pick up several contacts from the list to send them a single e-mail.

I used to a table control allows user to select multiple records (usually with ctrl). But it turned out that in Access datasheet the continuous selection is only allowed.

Then I thought of adding editable checkbox column to a readonly table, where the user would be able to mark the desired rows. But I have not found a way how to do this in Access. It seems that the method Append in Fields collection is available only for tables and indexes, but not for queries or recordsets.

I have also read advice to get rid of the subform, and display data in listbox with property multiselect = extended. But in this case, the user will lose the benefits of the table: he can't move and resize columns, sort and filter data.

I have a feeling that the decision should be very simple, I just do not know the conventional way of how to implement this functionality in Access. Help me please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a datasheet (for filter, sort, resize), then an editable checkbox is really your only option.

The column can be part of the original table, or create a join table with ID and check column, where you add the IDs from all records of your base table.

In the subform you can set all controls except the checkbox to `Locked = True`.

Comment: Do I have to create a temporary table for that and fill it every time when I populate datasheet? It sounds a pretty weird for me. Is it really a normal practice in Access?

Comment: Yes. -- The"normal" practice IMHO is a multi-select listbox. But if you need the additional features of a datasheet, you need an editable column to select arbitrary records.

Answer (score 2):

This is doable by utilizing the RecordsetClone property of the sub form. Here is an example:

```
Sub GetSelectedValue()

Dim rs as Recordset
Dim sContact as String

Set rs = Me.[SubFormName Goes Here].Form.RecordsetClone    
rs.MoveFirst
rs.Move Me.[SubFormName Goes Here].Form.SelTop - 1
sContact = rs![Recordset Column Name Goes Here] 

Set rs = Nothing
End Sub
```

You can put this on the main form via a button control that takes the active row contact and places that name into a listbox on your main form. Once the user has made all their choices, you can then run your e-mail program off the names within the listbox.

Comment: Thank you, Craig. I think it's a good approach too, but i've already done it by Andre's proposal.

Comment: As long as you have your program running the way you like, then all is good. :-)